# Capacitor charge - why a resistance is needed?

Tags: capacitor, resistors

I'm wondering why every example of a circuit capable of charging a capacitor has a resistor in it. Why is this resistor necessary?

[image: Sample RC circuit]

Comment: Are the contacts of switch S rated for infinite current? If not, better have some R, or you'll have dead former switch S.

Comment: In practice there will always be some resistance. In the 'ideal' case with zero resistance, the charging current will be an impulse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All real circuit has some resistance, even superconductor [upd: no, superconductor has no resistance]. You could assign it value 0 Ohm, but then if you try to calculate the transition effects, you will see unreal stuff like infinite current, division by zero, etc.

By the way, the scheme itself is quite common. Almost all circuit has input capacitance and when switched on they are charged quickly, because the only resistance in system is the one of the wires. This is called inrush current. If this current is too high, it can burn fuses, pop aluminum capacitors, etc. To deal with it the resistance is increased for the fist moments.

Comment: Superconductor has no resistance, but it does still have inductance.

Comment: Yes, it appears so. It's time to ask the boss to work a little with superconductors.

Comment: Can't the ESR of the capacitor itself be substantial compared to the wires themselves??

Comment: I would say never, but let's say rarely.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary, but it makes things simpler. Without it you have (hypothetically) infinite current when the switch is closed, and that's hard to reason about.

Answer (score 1):

When you analyze this circuit with zero resistance, you get some infinite values that make it impossible to get a meaningful answer. However, if you analyze with a resistance and then take the limit as R -> 0, you still get meaningful answers.